# LED Light Bar set up, through cigarette lighter

Tags: led, power-electronics, automotive, fuses

The below image is the setup I would like to have in my car.

I tried to illustrate it as best as i can. I do not want to go straight to my car battery for warranty purposes.

So my questions are:

1. What size fuses do I use and where do i put them? I am able to insert a fuse at the cigarette lighters.
2. What size wires must i use?
3. Is there a better way?

Please feel free to edit the image.

[image]

Thanks

I hope there is enough information

Comment: that looks like 130W which is quite a lot for a cigaretter lighter socket.

Comment: @Jansen You can extract 10 A from many lighter sockets but not all.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that you should be OK, except that, if your 27 watt LEDs are 12 volt, they won't work, since in series each will only receive 6 volts. In comments Jasen suggested that the current drain may be too high. [This discussion](http://If%20your%2027%20watt%20LEDs%20are%2012%20volt,%20they%20won't%20work,%20since%20in%20series%20each%20will%20only%20receive%206%20volts.%20Otherwise,%20the%20wiring%20is%20straightforward%20except%20for%20Jasen's%20objection.%20126%20watts%20is%2010.5%20amps%20at%2012%20volts,%20and) suggests that cigarette lighters are fused anywhere between 5 and 20 amps, so you'll need to check your owner's manual to find out just what your fuse really is. Also, I suggest getting rid of plug 2.3. The last thing you want to do is have someone plug in a lighter while the LEDs are on, since this will probably blow the fuse, and they are a pain to replace. Make sure any wiring is rated at the fuse current - Google on "ampacity" and use the smaller ratings for a given wire size.